# How can I update 2 collections at the same time using Node.js/Mongoose/MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Thank you for taking your time reading this.

I am making blog app with Node.js/Mongoose/MongoDB. Currently, I'm struggling to figure out how to update 2 collections at the same time.
My userSchema has arrays of postSchema, and I would like to update both users and posts collections whenever I update documents.

My code is here:

```js
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String,
    author: String
});

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    displayName: String,
    provider: String,
    posts: [postSchema],
    drafts: [postSchema]
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

```js
app.post('/edit/:title', function (req, res) {
        Post.findOneAndUpdate({ title: req.params.title }, {
            title: req.body.title,
            content: req.body.content
        }, function (error, post) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                res.redirect('/dashboard');
            }
        });
});
```

At the moment, my code only updates posts collection, and arrays of postSchema inside users collection stay the same. Could anyone help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you intentionally keeping two copies of the post data rather than a reference to a `Post`?

Comment: Do you mean 'posts' and 'drafts' inside User? I use those for different purposes... Please just ignore that part. I just want to update postSchemas inside users collection.

Comment: There is a collection for Posts, then Posts are also embedded in the User schema. It appears to be duplicating data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it 2 ways

**Option 1**

.then() & .catch() block

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate({
    Do your stuff here
}).then((result)=>{
    Do your stuff here with result from step above
}).catch((err)=>{
    Handle Error
});
```

**Option 2**

Use async/ await

```
async function (req, res) {
      const postResult = await Post.findOneAndUpdate({ title: req.params.title }, {
                     title: req.body.title,
                     content: req.body.content
                     });
      const userResult = await User.findOneAndUpdate({Do some stuff here});
      
      if(!postResult || !userResult){
       return new Error(...)
      }
      return
```

Since there is not much of code shared this cannot be used as is.. but the logic behind these options will remain the same even in your code ..

Comment: The async/await code should be wrapped in a try/catch and errors handled there (e.g. `res.status(500)`) to emulate the catch above